# Replacing html tags with regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, replaceall

Say you have a string that contains text from an html file and you do:

```
    content = content.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

I know this will essentially remove all the html tags.  However, if I want to keep tags which look like:

```
    <> or < (any type/amount of blank space here) >
```

is it possible to modify the replaceAll to accomplish that?  If so, how?  Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Comment: How about just `"</?\\s*[^<\\s>]+\\s*/?>"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
content = content.replaceAll("<[^>]*[^\\s>][^>]*>", "");
```

That should match tags that have at least one non-whitespace character in them.